# Classic electrostatics image problem surface charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, method-of-images

In the classic image problem of electrostatics (an infinite conducting planar sheet and a point charge *above* the sheet), one calculates the potential and hence field in the region above the conducting sheet.  Then the standard surface charge calculation applies the boundary condition
\begin{equation}
\sigma = \epsilon_0 \left( \vec{\mathbf{E}}_{above} - \vec{\mathbf{E}}_{below} \right) \cdot \hat{n} 
\end{equation}
at the conducting sheet, *taking $\vec{\mathbf{E}}_{below}$ to be zero*.

I cannot see why the field must vanish in the region below the sheet; at any rate, this region is not the interior of any conductor.  Can anybody explain why (rigorously)?

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry, I think I understand now. One simply applies a Uniqueness theorem to the region below the conducting sheet (which I should have mentioned in the question, is *grounded*) to conclude that $\vec{\mathbf{E}}_{below} = 0$.

Comment: That's exactly correct.